# Cannot catch auth/email-already-in-use when Updating Email

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having a problem with the function to update the user email. The function does three main things. First, it changes the email to the Firebase Auth, then it updates the email in the database, and last it sends the email verification.

I'm able to catch the incorrect password error, but when it comes to `auth/email-already-in-use` error, it doesn't work.

The problem is that I'm updating the email in the database and sending the verification email, but it's not updating the email in Firebase Auth.

component.ts (UPDATED!!)

```
  updateEmail(emailForm: NgForm){
    let newEmail = emailForm.value.newEmail;
    let password = emailForm.value.password;
    this.profileProvider.updateEmail(newEmail, password)
    .then(value => {
      this.showEditEmail = !this.showEditEmail;
      this.authService.emailVerification()
      .then(value => {
        this.snackBar.open('Su correo ha sido modificado con éxito. Hemos enviado un enlace de verificación a su nueva dirección de correo electrónico');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`Chao ${error.message}`)
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(`Hola ${error.message}`);
      this.emailPasswordError = error.message;
      } else {
        this.emailPasswordError = null;
      }
    })
  }
```

profile-provider.service.ts

```
updateEmail(newEmail: string, password: string): firebase.Promise<any> {
    const credential =  firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider
      .credential(this.currentUser.email, password);
    return this.currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
      .then( user => {
        this.currentUser.updateEmail(newEmail).then( user => {
          this.userProfile.update({ email: newEmail });
        });
      });
  };
```

Comment: It is not clear. Are you getting an `auth/email-already-in-use` error when calling `this.currentUser.updateEmail` ?

Comment: That's exactly what I don't know. I just get that error in my console but I'm unable to catch it. That's why every `console.log()` has a prefix

Comment: I think updateEmail is throwing it due to the new email already being used, you can catch here: `this.currentUser.updateEmail(newEmail).then( user => {
          this.userProfile.update({ email: newEmail });
        }, error => {console.log(error);});`

Comment: Thanks for your help @bojeil. Now I'm able to catch the error but in the service and I need to catch it in my component so I can show an error message and so my function stop working, because now it's not updating the e-mail as expected, but I'm still showing a snackbar telling that the email was succesfully updated. I just updated updateEmail function in the component by the way.

Comment: I already solve what I asked you in my last comment. Please, post your comment as an aswer so I can check it correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it Claudio. I posted my comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `updateEmail` is throwing it due to the new email already being used, you can catch here:

```
this.currentUser.updateEmail(newEmail).then(user => { 
  this.userProfile.update({ email: newEmail });
}, error => {console.log(error);});
```