# Firebase on Express - Can't return response to client with .catch(error)

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

I've searched for hours and could not find a single relevant thing about this.

I am using firebase on my express web server for user (admin) authentification. I basically have a separate control panel for the admins separate from the mobile app so we can control the data from the users.

I currently have this post address that does the following:

```
app.post('/createNewAdminAccount', function(req, res){
  const password = bcryptPassword(bcryptDetails, req.body.password);
  const username = req.body.username;
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  let userExists = false;

  function userExistsResponse(){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ "userExists": true }));
  }

  const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, String(password));
  promise.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error.message);
    userExistsResponse();
  });
});
```

The way I have `userExistsResponse();` isn't exactly how I have it, but for the sake of clarity, it's like that.

It seems that the `.catch()` function can only accept `console.log()`. I even looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980318/cannot-catch-auth-email-already-in-use-when-updating-email) which suggests stacking a `.then(), error(error)` but that doesn't work no matter how I write it, and using `catch(error)` doesn't seem to work either.

The goal is to see that the user is authenticated and respond to the client with a message as such. I've tried setting a variable to `true` (as you can see by the leftover `let userExists = false` variable), calling a function, doing a `.then()` statement without a `.catch()` (causes the server to break with an error), etc. None of it works, and after looking through YouTube videos, Firebase documentation, and StackOverflow, I have not found a useful answer.

**FIXED** *Credit: 0x17*

```
app.post('/createNewAdminAccount', authenticated, function(req, res){
  const password = String(bcryptPassword(bcryptDetails, req.body.password));
  const username = req.body.username;

  admin.auth().getUserByEmail(username)
    .then(function(userRecord) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'userExists': true }));
      console.log('User Exists');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password);
      promise.catch(function(error){
        console.log(error.message);
      });
      console.log('User Created');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way i see it, for the `createNewAdminAccount` route, Why not you do a check for the user in the first place using `admin.auth().getUserByEmail()`; analyse it's response code `auth/email-already-exists` or a combination of some listed in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors) and then proceed with `admin.auth().createUser()` ?

Also if your goal is to **just** authenticate the user, should you not be using the below mentioned method and analyze the error code for the same ?

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I put the `.res` functions in the `.then()` and put the `auth.create...` in the error `.catch()`